# How to change the name of standard field in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I really have problem to find how to change the name (label) of a standard field in Netsuite (e.g. the field "Amount" which is printed on the Sales Order, I want to change it to "Net Amount").

I know that over Setup-> Company -> Rename Records/Transactions I can change the record and transaction labels, but there isn't any possibility to change a "standard field" name...

Thanks!

[Sales Order Netsuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6qtI.png)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to change the label on the printed invoice, have a look at Customization > Forms > Transaction Form PDF Layouts and find the PDF layout for Sales Orders. You should be able to edit the labels and layout as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to any Sales Order and choose Customize > Customize Form. (Alternatively, go to Customization > Forms > Transaction Forms then find the form for Sales Order). In the Printing Fields tab, under Columns, you should be able to see the row for Amount and change the label from Amount to Net Amount if you wish.